# Is there any safe way to ensure an arbitrary drop happens before some expensive computation?

Tags: multithreading, rust, raii

I've found that `mem::drop` does not necessary run near where it gets called, which likely results in `Mutex` or `RwLock` guards being held during expensive computations.  How can I control when `drop` gets called?

As a simple example, I've made the following test for a zeroing drop of cryptographic material work by using `unsafe { ::std::intrinsics::drop_in_place(&mut s); }` instead of simply `::std::mem::drop(s)`.

```
#[derive(Debug, Default)]
pub struct Secret<T>(pub T);

impl<T> Drop for Secret<T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe { ::std::intrinsics::volatile_set_memory::<Secret<T>>(self, 0, 1); }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Default)]
pub struct AnotherSecret(pub [u8; 32]);

impl Drop for AnotherSecret {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe { ::std::ptr::write_volatile::<$t>(self, AnotherSecret([0u8; 32])); }
        assert_eq!(self.0,[0u8; 32]);
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    macro_rules! zeroing_drop_test {
        ($n:path) => {
            let p : *const $n;
            {
                let mut s = $n([3u8; 32]);  p = &s;  
                unsafe { ::std::intrinsics::drop_in_place(&mut s); }  
            }
            unsafe { assert_eq!((*p).0,[0u8; 32]); }
        }
    }
    #[test]
    fn zeroing_drops() {
        zeroing_drop_test!(super::Secret<[u8; 32]>);
        zeroing_drop_test!(super::AnotherSecret);
    }
}
```

This test fails if I use `::std::mem::drop(s)` or even

```
#[inline(never)]
pub fn drop_now<T>(_x: T) { }
```

It's obviously fine to use `drop_in_place` for a test that a buffer gets zeroed, but I'd worry that calling `drop_in_place` on a `Mutex` or `RwLock` guard might result in use after free.

These two guards could maybe be handled with this approach :

```
#[inline(never)]
pub fn drop_now<T>(t: mut T) {
    unsafe { ::std::intrinsics::drop_in_place(&mut t); }
    unsafe { ::std::intrinsics::volatile_set_memory::<Secret<T>>(&t, 0, 1); }
}
```

Comment: I've raise this as an issue with the rust compiler https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1850 after identifying that CPU pipelining, etc. were not the culprits.

Comment: Answer there is to never put secret key material on the stack because anything on the stack gets copied around.

Comment: maybe add a [fence](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/fn.fence.html). AIUI that should prevent reordering.

Comment: I tried that, not the problem here.  I should add a correct answer

Answer (score 4):

Answer from https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1850 :

In debug mode, any call to `::std::mem::drop(s)` physically moves `s` on the stack, so `p` points to an old copy that does not get erased.  And `unsafe { ::std::intrinsics::drop_in_place(&mut s); }` works because it does not move `s`.

In general, there is no good way to either prevent LLVM from moving values around on the stack, or else to zero after moving them, so you must never put cryptographically sensitive data on the stack.  Instead you must `Box` any sensitive data, like say

```
#[derive(Debug, Default)]
pub struct AnotherSecret(Box<[u8; 32]>);

impl Drop for AnotherSecret {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        *self.0 = [0u8; 32];
    }
}
```

There should be no problem with `Mutex` or `RwLock` because they can safely leave residue on the stack when they are `drop`ed.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**: side effects.

Optimizers in general, and LLVM in particular, operate under the as-if rule: you build a program which has a specific observable behavior, and the optimizer is given free reign to produce whatever binary it wants as long as it has the very same observable behavior.

Note that the burden of proof is on the compiler. That is, when calling an opaque function (defined in another library, for example) the compiler *has* to assume it may have side effects. Furthermore, side effects cannot be re-ordered, as this could change the observable behavior.

In the case of `Mutex`, for example, acquiring and releasing the `Mutex` is generally opaque for the compiler (it requires an OS call), so it is seen as a side effect. I would expect compilers not to fiddle with those.

On the other hand, your `Secret` is a tricky case: most of the time there is no side-effect in dropping the secret (zeroing out to-be-released memory is a dead-write, to be optimized out), which is why you need to go out of your way to ensure it occurs... by convincing the compiler that there are side effects using a `volatile` write.

Comment: The presented code **does** use volatile writes though.

Comment: Yes, which is why I say that the OP is going out of its way to convince the compiler that there are side effects.

Comment: @Shepmaster: What do you mean "fail", I don't see any failure related to the use of volatile in the OP's question, I only see the non-volatile cases failing (because dead-writes).

Comment: Maybe I'm still asleep? OP says "This test fails if I use ::std::mem::drop(s)". The `Drop` implementation uses volatile writes either way, but *the way that drop is invoked* changes behavior.

Comment: @Shepmaster: Ah! I'm the one asleep. I thought the OP meant using `drop` without a special `Drop` implementation. Indeed, I can reproduce the issue replacing the `drop_in_place` intrinsics by `mem::drop` in the macro. Which is interesting, as it happens even in Debug mode, and NOT using `mem::drop` causes everything to work. There might be some undefined behavior at play here, since the OP is using a pointer to "moved" memory...

Comment: I donno if Rust's `Mutex` is truly opaque but the long running computation certainly won't be opaque.  It's possible the CPU's pipelining caused this particular one.

Comment: I'll try this with a `std::thread::sleep` and/or some heavy computation to see if maybe it's just the CPU.